# how to change field name or group in mongoldb (aggregation) with particular condition after match result's array

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hello guys i have stuck in a situation hope you will help me to get rid of it :).

consider I have a user collection which is `users` , whcih is containing 2 documents

```
  [{_id: 5f760e02f28c8b72b0101a24,
  email: test@demo.com,
   },
  {_id: 5f760e02f28c8b72b0101a25,
  email: test1@demo.com }]
```

now i want both user , so i have used given aggregation stage.

```
$match:{
_id:{$in:[ObjectId('5f760e02f28c8b72b0101a24'),ObjectId('5f760e02f28c8b72b0101a25')]}
}
```

until now everything is working fine. my problem is i just want to group user's email after getting result of first stage of aggression,  which is `$match`.
**result with $match**

```
[{_id: 5f760e02f28c8b72b0101a24,
  email: test@demo.com,
   },
  {_id: 5f760e02f28c8b72b0101a25,
  email: test1@demo.com }]
```

I mean, after first stage `$match`, i want to filter result by `5f760e02f28c8b72b0101a24` _id,which is first users _id and want to change `email` key , with `applicantEmail` in final aggregation result, if condition satisfied.

**Expected result**

```
[{_id: 5f760e02f28c8b72b0101a24,
  applicantEmail: test@demo.com,
   },
  {_id: 5f760e02f28c8b72b0101a25,
  email: test1@demo.com }]
```

or any alternative idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
db.users.update(
   {_id: ObjectId('5f760e02f28c8b72b0101a24')},
   {$rename: {'email': 'applicantEmail'}}
)
```

...if I did get you right.

Comment: no i dont want to update field, i just want result with different key. just quick check, i have edited my question.